# How to force windows to show latest version of webpage?

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

**Edit:** Also, I can reach via tor browser

Things I have tried: 
Clearing all browser cache,history on all my browsers.
Resetting windows network adapter.

My webhosting had expired and it was showing "Account Suspended" when I visited my website. However, I renewed my hosting 24 hours ago. On my phone browser, my site is displayed properly. On other PCs on my network, my site is displayed properly. But on my work PC, my browsers (Edge/Chrome/FF) are still showing the same "Account Suspended" message.
 I can reach the site using kproxy, but cannot save any wordpress appearance settings.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Access using IP?

Comment: @mcalex same result

Comment: may be it is cached in your intermediate servers (possibly DNS Servers or Cache Server).

Comment: You have to wait for things to propagate. Give it 24-48 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who responded. I don't know what was the reason, but turns out I just had to wait some more. It's weird though, as other devices on the same network were rendering the updated page.

Answer (score 0):

I would try incognito mode on your work pc to see if that makes a difference. Press Ctrl+Shift+N to get an incognito window (at least in Chrome that works).

If that makes a difference, either cookies or browser extensions could be the culprit. Try turning off any extensions or deleting cookies; note that this logs you out of all websites.

Another explanation could be that your workplace might have a private cache running on their network. Ask your system administrator about this. Note that even if you use your work pc at home, it might connect to your workplace internet connection through a VPN.

By the way, pressing Ctrl+F5 is a shortcut to reloading a web site bypassing the local browser cache, but as you cleared the cache that shouldn't make a difference. And it won't bypass any cache set up on the workplace internet connection.

Clearing the history or resetting the network card should not matter at all in this.